# After 500000 records MySQL become extremely slow

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, view

I am using phpMyAdmin 4.2.7.1. MySQL 5.6.16. MS Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, 4GB RAM, Intel Xeon E5-2620 @ 2.00GHz. Few days ago I had encounter the problem in MySQL query which worked fast before. In past on average query would return results faster then 5 minutes now it can't return results even after few hours. This is the view I have created:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW okp_view AS 
     select q.MessageId AS MessageId,
q.SenderTimeStamp AS SenderTimeStamp,
r.GsbId AS GsbId,
r.ReceiverTimeStamp AS ReceiverTimeStamp,
r.FinalTimeStamp AS FinalTimeStamp,
k.ErrorCode AS ErrorCodeRes,
t.ErrorType AS ErrorTypeRes,
g.ID AS ID,
g.OIB AS OIB,
g.MssgText AS MssgText,
s.ErrorCode AS ErrorCodeResMssg,
m.ErrorType AS ErrorTypeMssg 
     from ((((((soap_req_env q 
join soap_res_env r) 
join soap_res_err k) 
join res_err_type t) 
join soap_message g) 
join soap_mssg_err s) 
join mssg_err_type m) 
     where ((q.MessageId = g.MessageId) 
and (g.ID = s.ID) 
and (s.ErrorCode = m.ErrorCode) 
and (q.MessageId = r.MessageId) 
and (r.GsbId = k.GsbId) 
and (k.ErrorCode = t.ErrorCode)) 
order by q.SenderTimeStamp desc;
```

View contains more then 500000 records.
These are indexes on MySQL tables:

```
TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME
mssg_err_type,ErrorCode
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,PRIMARY
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,fk_Registar_e_poruka_za_OKP_Sifarnik_posiljatelja_e_poruka1_idx
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,fk_Registar_e_poruka_za_OKP_Sifarnik_zivotnih_situacija1_idx
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,fk_Registar_e_poruka_za_OKP_Sifarnik_tema1_idx
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,fk_Registar_e_poruka_za_OKP_Sifarnik_razine_pouzdanosti_vje_idx
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,fk_Registar_e_poruka_za_OKP_Sifarnik_tipa_privitka1_idx
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,fk_Registar_e_poruka_za_OKP_Sifarnik_frekvencije_slanja_por_idx
registar_e_poruka_za_okp,fk_Registar_e_poruka_za_OKP_Sifarnik_statusa_e_poruke1_idx
res_err_type,ErrorCode
soap_message,PRIMARY
soap_message,MessageId
soap_mssg_err,ID
soap_mssg_err,ErrorCode
soap_req_env,PRIMARY
soap_res_env,PRIMARY
soap_res_env,MessageId
soap_res_err,GsbId
soap_res_err,ErrorCode
```

Now MySQL gives me data for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM okp_view WHERE SenderTimeStamp>="2015-05-25" 
Showing rows 0 - 24 (2132 total, Query took 13.9374 seconds.)
```

If I try to retrieve larger subset with:

```
SELECT * FROM okp_view WHERE SenderTimeStamp>="2015-05-24"
```

but it takes to long.

How can I improve database schema to optimize database and speed up data retrieval.

EDIT:
If I use query without view it takes to long:

```
select * from soap_req_env q, soap_res_env r, soap_res_err k, res_err_type t, soap_message g, soap_mssg_err s, mssg_err_type m
where q.messageid=g.messageid
and g.id=s.id
and s.errorcode=m.errorcode
and q.messageid=r.messageid
and r.gsbid=k.gsbid
and k.errorcode=t.errorcode
and q.sendertimestamp>="2015-05-15"
ORDER BY `q`.`SenderTimeStamp` DESC
```

Result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` is

```
Variable_name   Value
bulk_insert_buffer_size     8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown     OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now     OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename     ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now     OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size     16777216
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering     all
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_sort_buffer_size     1048576
join_buffer_size    262144
key_buffer_size     16777216
myisam_sort_buffer_size     8388608
net_buffer_length   8192
preload_buffer_size     32768
read_buffer_size    262144
read_rnd_buffer_size    524288
sort_buffer_size    524288
sql_buffer_result   OFF
```

Structure of my tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `soap_req_env` (
 `MessageId` char(36) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `SenderTimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`MessageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci

    CREATE TABLE `soap_res_env` (
 `MessageId` char(36) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `GsbId` char(36) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `ReceiverTimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `FinalTimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`GsbId`),
 KEY `MessageId` (`MessageId`),
 CONSTRAINT `soap_res_env_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MessageId`) REFERENCES `soap_req_env` (`MessageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci

CREATE TABLE `soap_res_err` (
 `GsbId` char(36) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `ErrorCode` char(4) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `GsbId` (`GsbId`,`ErrorCode`),
 KEY `ErrorCode` (`ErrorCode`),
 CONSTRAINT `soap_res_err_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ErrorCode`) REFERENCES `res_err_type` (`ErrorCode`),
 CONSTRAINT `soap_res_err_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`GsbId`) REFERENCES `soap_res_env` (`GsbId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci

 CREATE TABLE `res_err_type` (
 `ErrorCode` char(4) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `ErrorType` text COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `ErrorCode` (`ErrorCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci

CREATE TABLE `soap_message` (
 `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `MessageId` char(36) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `OIB` char(11) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `MssgText` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `MessageId` (`MessageId`,`OIB`),
 CONSTRAINT `soap_message_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MessageId`) REFERENCES `soap_req_env` (`MessageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=571197 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci

CREATE TABLE `soap_mssg_err` (
 `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ErrorCode` char(4) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 KEY `ID` (`ID`),
 KEY `ErrorCode` (`ErrorCode`),
 CONSTRAINT `soap_mssg_err_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ErrorCode`) REFERENCES `mssg_err_type` (`ErrorCode`),
 CONSTRAINT `soap_mssg_err_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `soap_message` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=571197 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci

CREATE TABLE `mssg_err_type` (
 `ErrorCode` char(4) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `ErrorType` text COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `ErrorCode` (`ErrorCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci
```

Comment: One thing is obvious you are creating view and then using select statement from the view and unfortunately in views you can not use index. However if you make the selection based on orginal select query to create the view and having indexes on tables will be faster than what you are getting now `~14 sec`

Comment: Please use this syntax:  `... JOIN t ON ...` instead of `JOIN ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE soap_req_env;`

Comment: @RickJames 
CREATE TABLE `soap_req_env` (
 `MessageId` char(36) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `SenderTimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`MessageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci

Comment: Please edit the question to add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; the index list you provided is not detailed enough.  Also, let's see `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The evils of UUIDs**

(I'm going out on a limb here, not knowing for sure that a UUID is involved.)

> MessageId CHAR(36) COLLATE utf8... PRIMARY KEY

That smells like a hex string that is a "UUID"; I am assuming that it is.

**Problem #1**

`CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8` consumes 108 bytes everywhere it occurs.  It seems to be a key in multiple tables, and possibly shows up in secondary (InnoDB implicitly includes the `PRIMARY KEY` in every secondary key.)  For 500K records, that adds up to many megabytes, possibly gigabytes.

Fix #1:

`CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET ascii` would be only 36 bytes.

Fix #2:

Convert it to binary and store it in `BINARY(16)`, which would take only 16 bytes.  My [UUID blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) provides the code for the conversion.

**Problem #2**

UUIDs are extremely *random*.  Once the UUID index is bigger than can be cached in innodb_buffer_pool_size (or key_buffer_size, if MyISAM), more and more of the lookups have to hit the disk.  For example, when the index is 20 times as big as the cache, 95% (or more) of the lookups require a disk hit.

Comment: I have problem with this. When I tried to test it I've got something unexpected. First I have inserted UUID like this `INSERT INTO  test ( UUID ) VALUES (UuidToBin( "6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-0040f4311e29" ));` result for `SELECT UuidFromBin(UUID) FROM test;` was `36636364373830632d626162612d313032362d393536342d303034306634333131653239`

Comment: Looks like there is an `HEX()` call somewhere in what you showed.  Was `UUID` declared to be `BINARY(16)`?  Search for UuidFromBin -- I see several equivalent functions.  Try them instead of mine.